# `xinit /usr/bin/firefox` vs `xinit firefox`

Tags: x11, xinit

`xinit /usr/bin/firefox` seems to do what's expected: to run firefox without a window manager.

`xinit firefox` seems to do similar, but with a small `xterm` running behind.

Can someone explain me what's happening here?

Comment: As I don't use `xinit` I can only recommend defining alias `firefox='xinit /usr/bin/firefox'`. Problem gone.

Comment: If you want to use `xinit firefox` for convenience and you use zsh, just `alias -g firefox="/usr/bin/firefox"` and zsh will replace it automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that you simply do not have an `~/.xinitrc` file.  When `xinit` starts it looks for that file and if it does not find it then it runs a tiny `xterm`.  To be exact it runs:

```
xterm  -geometry  +1+1  -n  login  -display  :0
```

Also, the command line to `xinit` is:

```
xinit [ [ client ] options ... ] [ -- [ server ] [ display ] options ... ]
```

We can ignore the part after `--` (right side) since that is for the server (X server) side, and you are simply using defaults in there.  Now for the client side (left side) you have something a little ambiguous: `[ [ client ] options ... ]`.  In other words `xinit` give preference to *options* instead of *client*.

That behaviour is actually described in the `man`:

> Both the client program name and the server program name must begin with a slash (/) or a period  (.).   Otherwise, they  are  treated as an arguments to be appended to their respective startup lines.  This makes it possible to add arguments (for example, foreground and background colors) without having to retype the whole command line.

Therefore:

- `/usr/bin/firefox` is an X client, so it is executed
- `firefox` is a client *option*, so `xterm` is executed, with those arguments above and an extra argument (option): "firefox".  Exactly this:

  ```
  xterm  -geometry  +1+1  -n  login  -display  :0  firefox
  ```